# What does "of or relating to" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions

Looked up the definition of "epistemic."

The definition is "of or relating to knowledge or knowing."

...Which seems rather vague to me. I'm not sure what "of or relating to" means, exactly. Please explain?

Comment: The phrase is used in a generic sense to make an adjective out of a noun.

Comment: What does "of" mean?  What does "relating to" mean?  Put them together.

Comment: Some dictionaries use/d the full monty, eg Dictionary.reference.com: _Imperial_: of, like, or pertaining to an empire. >> _of/belonging to an empire_: the Imperial Army // _[in some way] like an empire_: Here in other words is a phenomenon with an essential nature and on a scale that can only be described as imperial. // _relating or pertaining to an empire_: Imperial War Museum

Answer (score 2):

The point of this wording is to cover all possible usages of the word.  Consider the following meanings:

- "of knowledge"
- "of knowing"
- "relating to knowledge"
- "relating to knowing"

Depending on the context of where the word is used, the specific meaning will change, but this wording captures all of the above meanings.

Comment: I don't really understand what they mean separately either.

Comment: If you understand the nature of the effects of depth on a scuba diver and the resultant nitrogen narcosis,  it could be said that you have a knowledge "of, or relating to, dissolved gasses in the blood."